# Function which enables to select different background color of each element from different color in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, select, onchange

I have a project which is the note-taking website.
When someone adds a note it is stored in local storage in the form of an array and a Javascript function works which calls the stored element and runs `for each` on the elements.
Here is the Javascript code:

```
function showNote2() {
    console.log("Show");
    let note = localStorage.getItem("notes");
    if(note == null){
        noteData = []
        // message.innerText = "Please Add a Note"
    }
    else{
        noteData = JSON.parse(note);
    };
    let showBox = "";
    noteData.forEach(function show(element, index) {
        showBox += `<div class="noteCard my-2 mx-2 card" id="card4" style="width: 18rem;">
        <select id="mySelect" class="clr-btn" style="text-align:center" onchange="change_color()">
        <option id="bckgrnd-clr" value="white">Background Color</option>
        <option id="red" value="Red">Red</option>
        <option id="green" value="Green">Green</option>
        <option id="blue" value="Blue">Blue</option>
        </select>
                <div class="card-body" id="card3">
                  <h5 class="cardtitle">Note
                  ${index + 1}
                  </h5>
                  <p class="card-text"> 
                  ${element}
                  </p>
                  <button id="${index}" onclick="deleteNote(this.id)" class="btn btn-primary">Delete Note</a>
                </div>
              </div>   `
            })
              let showNote3 = document.getElementById("notes2");
              if(noteData.length != 0){
                  showNote3.innerHTML = showBox;
              }else{
                  showNote3.innerHTML = "Please add a Note"
              }
}
```

In the above code, `select` gives us the option to choose a color for the note, now I want to add a function to `onchange` which can help me choose a different color for different notes.
The function I used was working only on the first-note and setting the color of all notes according to the selected option of first-note.
The color will be applied on class with `card-body`

I am building this for practice in Javascript. Any hints would be appreciated, as this is something new for me
Update:
This is the solution I applied after getting the idea from the comments.

```
function change_color(index) {
    let note = localStorage.getItem("notes");
    if(note != null ){
        let colorApply = document.getElementById("card3")
        let elm1 = document.getElementById(index)
        let color = elm1.options[elm1.selectedIndex].value;
        document.colorApply.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
    else{
        `Note is Empty`
    }
```

Now this is the error i am getting at `color`

"Cannot read properties of null (reading 'options')"
Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: You'll need to do something similar to what you've done for the delete button - IDs need to be unique

Comment: As an aside - if this is just some general practice, it'd be worth looking at jQuery too; it's just a javascript package that makes a lot of the html manipulation easier.

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan I look into jQuery

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan In delete it is simple, i just applied `.splice` and then stored the value in local storage

Comment: then it looks like you just need to make sure the IDs are unique - maybe append the index to the existing ID?

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan got that
Do YOU some more ideas on how to include these IDs into the function in such a way that the function performs as it should be?

Comment: Same as how you've done it here: `button id="${index}"`

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan let me try and i will get back here if i face any issue

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan please check the solution. This would work if i can resolve `option` issue

Comment: I suspect the issue is because you can't start a HTML ID with a number - if you try changing it to a meaningful ID with a number at the end. For example `id="mySillyID{index}"`

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan still didn't worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See the working snippet. :)**

In your loop, change code like this:

```js
let elm1 = document.getElementById(index)
```

to

```js
let showNote3 = document.getElementById(`card${index}`);
let colorApply = document.getElementById(`card${index}`)
let elm1 = document.getElementById(`mySelect${index}`)
```

and in your HTML

```html
`<div class="noteCard my-2 mx-2 card" id="card${index}" ...` />
`<select id=`mySelect${index}` class="clr-btn" style="text-align:center" onchange="change_color()">`
```

Also when you have the element, you do not need to use `document`

```
// -> document.colorApply.style.backgroundColor = color;
colorApply.style.backgroundColor = color;
```

Finally, **you need to send the index of the note** into your change_color function.

```js
onchange="change_color(${index})"
```

```js
function showNote2() {
  console.log("Show");
  let note = null // localStorage.getItem("notes");
  if (note == null) {
    noteData = ['My Note 1', 'My Note 2']
    // message.innerText = "Please Add a Note"
  } else {
    noteData = JSON.parse(note);
  };
  let showBox = "";
  noteData.forEach(function show(element, index) {
    showBox += `
    <div class="noteCard my-2 mx-2 card" id="card${index}" style="width: 18rem;">
            <select id="mySelect${index}" class="clr-btn" style="text-align:center" onchange="change_color(${index})">
            <option id="bckgrnd-clr" value="white">Background Color</option>
            <option id="red" value="Red">Red</option>
            <option id="green" value="Green">Green</option>
            <option id="blue" value="Blue">Blue</option>
            </select>
            <div class="card-body" id="cardbody${index}">
                      <h5 class="cardtitle">Note ${index + 1}</h5>
                      <p class="card-text"> 
                      ${element}
                      </p>
                      <button id="btn${index}" onclick="deleteNote(this.id)" class="btn btn-primary">Delete Note</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>   
                  `
  })
  let showNote3 = document.getElementById("note");
  if (noteData.length != 0) {
    showNote3.innerHTML = showBox;
  } else {
    showNote3.innerHTML = "Please add a Note"
  }
}

function change_color(index) {
  let note = noteData[index] // localStorage.getItem("notes");
  if (note != null) {
    let colorApply = document.getElementById(`card${index}`)
    let elm1 = document.getElementById(`mySelect${index}`)
    let color = elm1.options[elm1.selectedIndex].value;
    colorApply.style.backgroundColor = color;
  } else {
    console.log(`Note is Empty`)
  }
}

showNote2()
```

```html
<h1>Notes</h1>
<div id='note' />
<button onclick='note' />
```

Comment: Spungin Thanks
In this HTML `<select id="card${index}" class="clr-btn" style="text-align:center" onchange="change_color()">` , right?
I have applied it still don't work, this is my code right now
Same issue

Comment: `function change_color(index) {
    let note = localStorage.getItem("notes");
    if(note != null ){
        let colorApply = document.getElementById("card3")
        let elm1 = document.getElementById(`card${index}`)
        let color = elm1.options[elm1.selectedIndex].value;
        document.colorApply.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
    else{
        `Note is Empty`
    }`

Comment: You need to stop hardcoding your IDs.  Also, you need to give your select an id to access the options - solution updated with general idea

Comment: Got it. Select is updated with ID to access the options
Now this is the code that i am using to access the selected option
`elm1.options[elm1.selectedIndex].value` but this returns null.
Infact it is not null

Comment: use `elm1.value` to get the `select` value.  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript?rq=1

Comment: I also looked at the question and tried all the answers before posting this one and unfortuantely, `elm1.value` also don't work
It gives the same error

Comment: `let elm1 = document.getElementById(\`mySelect${index}\`); console.log(elm1);`  If you log it, what does elm1 show?

Comment: It gives "null"

Comment: `let showNote3 = document.getElementById(`card${index}`);
let colorApply = document.getElementById(`card${index}`)
let elm1 = document.getElementById(`mySelect${index}`)`
All these codes return "null"

Comment: even (e=event object) returns undefined

Comment: OK @Code_2.  The final issue was you were not sending in an index into your change_color function.  I added a working snippet with the fix working.

Comment: Thanks, bro it worked
Learned something new.
I really appreciate YOUR help
Next thing I am trying to do is that colors remain the same when the browser is refresh
For that, I saved the color value in `local storage` with their `index`. And I called the `index` value at the top of the code so when the browser is refreshed colors remain the same but that didn't work.
Everything was back to normal(white).

Comment: i commented out the local storage calls so the snippet would run in stackoverflow

Comment: makes sense to store [{color:'Red', message:'Hello', modifed:234234}] in one array instead of many.  Then add an id field instead of using indexes. :)

Comment: noteData = ['My Note 1', 'My Note 2']
Can't get this?
Can YOU explain this?

Comment: This is the code i used

` localStorage.setItem(`clr${index}`, color)` this code in change_color function

`function backGroundClr(index) {
        let backclr2 = localStorage.getItem(`clr${index}`)
        colorApply.style.backgroundColor = backclr2
    console.log(backGroundClr)    
}`

Comment: open up another issue for this @code2

Comment: Hello @Steven
The answer YOU proposed works great but one issue is still there that it these code return me null
```let showNote3 = document.getElementById(card${index}); 
let colorApply = document.getElementById(card${index}) 
let elm1 = document.getElementById(mySelect${index})```
These are returning Null which is causing issue while making another function.
Any idea about this?